# Using AWS S3 SDK for node.js how to return filebody instead of 'Promise { pending }'

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Javascript isn't my number 1 language, however for an application I try to get objects from my S3 bucket. Eventually, I want these images to be included in some sort of HTML file, so I am looking for a method to create a base64 encode string.

Instead of the string, my function is returning 'Promise { pending }' and despite several attempts I am not getting it to work. This is my function at the moment:

```
async function getS3file() {
    try{
      var image = await s3.getObject({
        Bucket: 'Bucketname',
        Key: 'ImageKey'
      }).promise();
      
      return image.Body.toString('base64');
      
    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error('Could not retrieve file from S3')
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function getS3file() {
  return s3.getObject({
    Bucket: 'Bucketname',
    Key: 'ImageKey'
  })
  .promise()
  .then(file => file.Body)
  .then(body => body.toString('base64')
// .catch(...) 
}
```

then use

```
let image = await getS3file();
```

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean I have to put the last line in another async function? Otherwise it throws me a SyntaxError ('await is only valid in async function').

Comment: Yeah, awaits are only available in async functions. Alternatively, in sync functions, you can use `getS3file().then(image => { ... });`